# Search entire workbook with two criteria

Tags: vba, excel-2016

Gooday,  Pls I'm partially new to vba. I have several spreadsheet in a workbook for a work station that is prone to making shortage or surplus in daily delivery as a result of human errors. I want a scenario where I can search the entire workbook to extract data from Column K(which displays shortage or surplus)  , but it must meet a certain criteria in Column A(date of delivery) and Column D(location of delivery). In other words, I would like to search   Column K to know if there is shortage or surplus for any day  I choose to search based on date. Any form of assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution could include an InputBox and the Range.Find Method, where you search column A for date, read in the row, and look at column K of the same row. In fact, the Range.Find example is pretty easily modified for your needs.

But you mention location in Column D, so what constraints are on column D? You'll also need to be more specific about where/how you want to extract the data from column K.

Comment: Thanks Tom. As I mentioned earlier Column D displays delivery location. To be more specific, if I want to know either  there's a "shortage" or "surplus" for a delivery to  "LAGOS" on "2 Jan 2019". Using "LAGOS" and  "2 Jan 2019" as my search criteria I want vba to tell me if there's a "shortage" or "surplus" for delivery on the 2 Jan 2019 to Lagos via column K. Precisely, it should give me the answer on the same row with the criteria.

Comment: So if you have multiple input criteria, I've seen people design a user form to do what you need and have it run by macro. That's a little much to build from scratch on StackOverflow. Frankly, creating to a Pivot table from your source data with column A and Column D as filters sounds like it would meet your needs as well.